# How to use return value MATCH in formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm currently trying to get the row of a certain value I'm looking for. This works fine but now I want to use that value as the row I need to look in for other data.

At the moment I have this:

```
=IF(MATCH(A2; Stuklijsten!$A2:$A$65000;0); ""; Stuklijsten!$C$(MATCH(A2,Stuklijsten!$A2:A65000,0)))
```

But, obviously, that throws an error. I want the second MATCH to just return the row and use that in the IF statement.
So what I'm doing, in words, is: Find this value, if you find it return the value of a certain cell on that row.

Is this possible in a formula? If so, how should I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use Vlookup (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx)

```
=VLOOKUP(A2;Stuklijsten!$A2:$C$65000;3;FALSE)
```

Comment: You need to extend the range, e.g. =VLOOKUP(A2;Stuklijsten!$A2:$`C`$65000;3;FALSE)

Comment: So; when the value isn't found it shouldn't return anything (but it returns #N/A). How can I fix that?

Comment: If you have Excel 2007 or later IFERROR avoids repetition, e.g. `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2;Stuklijsten!$A2:$C$65000;3;FALSE);"No match")`

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
=Index(Stuklijsten!$C$2:$C$65000; match(A2;Stuklijsten!$A$2:$A$65000;0))
```

Or

```
=iferror(Index(Stuklijsten!$C$2:$C$65000; match(A2;Stuklijsten!$A$2:$A$65000;0));"")
```